# How to get ServiceStack RedisAdminUI to work with a license file for demo purposes

Tags: servicestack

Here is the [application](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RedisAdminUI) is question.

I've tried to put the license file in both the web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="servicestack:license" value="1001-e1JlZjoxMDAxLE5hbWU6VGVzdCBCdXNpbmVzcyxUeXBlOkJ1c2luZXNzLEhhc2g6UHVNTVRPclhvT2ZIbjQ5MG5LZE1mUTd5RUMzQnBucTFEbTE3TDczVEF4QUNMT1FhNXJMOWkzVjFGL2ZkVTE3Q2pDNENqTkQyUktRWmhvUVBhYTBiekJGUUZ3ZE5aZHFDYm9hL3lydGlwUHI5K1JsaTBYbzNsUC85cjVJNHE5QVhldDN6QkE4aTlvdldrdTgyTk1relY2eis2dFFqTThYN2lmc0JveHgycFdjPSxFeHBpcnk6MjAxMy0wMS0wMX0=" />
  </appSettings>
```

or in the [appsettings.license.txt](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RedisAdminUI/blob/master/src/RedisAdminUI/Global.asax.cs#L10) file, but both methods come back with an expired license exception. To my knowledge there was a license available for testing, but I can't seem to find that one anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Redis Admin UI live demo](http://redisadminui.servicestack.net/AjaxClient/) contains [over 100+ ServiceStack Web Services](http://redisadminui.servicestack.net/redis/metadata) which as it [exceeds ServiceStack's free-quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas), requires a valid commercial license to be able to run.

No license is required for using the free-quota's built-into ServiceStack's v4 packages which are permitted for small projects and evaluation purposes. The test/AGPL license keys do not unlock quota's for projects that use ServiceStack's v4 commercial NuGet packages.

Comment: We're a small shop, so the [Indi](https://servicestack.net/pricing)  is what will be purchasing. Thanks Demis.